# How to select div and get only unique id from selected div ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 3 divs. Or 5 is irrelevantly dynamic. I can select 1, and I can select all 5 or 0. I can only set unique IDs in a array. It is very important that div can be selected and unselected on click.

```
<div class="card-cst" *ngFor="let recipe of filteredRecipe">
    <div class="img">
        <img [src]="recipe.pictureUrl" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="h-2">
            <h2>
                {{ recipe.name }}
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button (click)="selectCard(recipe)">
            Select or unselect recipe
        </button>
    </div>
</div>



  selectCard(card){
    this.arrOfRecipeId.push(card);
    console.log(this.arrOfRecipeId); 
  }
```

Problem here?
Every click fills my array with what I shouldn't. It should only fill an existing id once. I also failed to set the select and unselect div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question completely but I believe you want to have toggle functionality.

You have, when card is clicked, check if id exist already, if yes remove it otherwise add it and that should work:

```js
selectCard(card) {
  const existingIndex = this.arrOfRecipeId.indexOf(card);
  if (existingIndex == -1) {
    this.arrOfRecipeId.push(card);
  } else {
    this.arrOfRecipeId.splice(existingIndex, 1);
  }
  console.log(this.arrOfRecipeId);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is work but how to add any class (ngClass) to selected card ?

Comment: you can use `ngClass` attribute in template and compare current card with selected and than set any class you want.